# Bockstein homomorphism and universal coefficient theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

The universal coefficient theorem tells us that we have a  s.e.s.

$$0 \to H_n(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p \to H_n(X; \mathbb{Z}_p) \xrightarrow{\beta} \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p) \to 0.$$

In particular, we can identify $\mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p) \cong \ker (H_{n-1}(X) \xrightarrow{\cdot p} H_{n-1}(X))$.

From the Bockstein homomorphism $\tilde{\beta}$ of the s.e.s.

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\cdot p} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\mathrm{mod}~p} \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0,$$

we obtain this snippet of the corresponding l.e.s. in homology:

$$\cdots \to H_{n}(X; \mathbb{Z}_p) \xrightarrow{\tilde{\beta}} H_{n-1}(X) \xrightarrow{\cdot p} H_{n-1}(X) \to \cdots,$$

so that we can infer $\mathrm{im}{\tilde{\beta}} = \ker (H_{n-1}(X) \xrightarrow{\cdot p} H_{n-1}(X)) \cong \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p)$. Hence, $\beta$ and $\tilde{\beta}$ have the same image.

Now, my question is whether indeed $i \circ \beta = \tilde{\beta}$, where $i: \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p) \hookrightarrow H_{n-1}(X)$ is the natural inclusion coming from the identification above.

I don't need a full explanation. A hint might be enough.

Comment: What happens to the Bockstein if $H_{n-1}(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)$ for some $k > 1$? What happens to $i \circ \beta$ in this case?

Comment: Then $\mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X),\mathbb{Z}_p) \cong \left<p^{k-1}\right> \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, but how do I go on from here?

Comment: I think both $i$ and $\beta$ will be nonzero, and their composite will be nonzero. But the Bockstein operation should be zero in this case.

Comment: For the Bockstein, we have this segment of the l.e.s.: $\cdots \to H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_p) \xrightarrow{\tilde{\beta}} \mathbb{Z}_{p^k} \xrightarrow{\cdot p} \mathbb{Z}_{p^k} \to \cdots$ and hence $\mathrm{im}(\tilde{\beta}) = \ker(\mathbb{Z}_{p^k} \xrightarrow{\cdot p} \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}) = \left<p^{k-1}\right> \neq 0$. In fact, the image of $\tilde{\beta}$ is always $\mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p)$, and therefore $\tilde{\beta}$ and $\beta$ have the same image. Or do I overlook something obvious here?

Comment: Maybe you're answering your own question...

Comment: Well, just because their images are the same, the maps are not necessarily the same. My bet is that the above is true. But it's not obvious to me why or why not...

Comment: May this be related to the Bockstein spectral sequence?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336202/passing-from-an-exact-sequence-of-groups-to-an-exact-sequence-of-homology-groups

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've obtained so far.

$$0 \to C(X) \xrightarrow{\cdot p} C(X) \xrightarrow{\mod p} C(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0$$

gives the long exact sequence in homology

$$\dots \to H_n(X) \xrightarrow{\cdot p} H_n(X) \xrightarrow{\mod p} H_n(X; \mathbb{Z}_p) \xrightarrow{\tilde{\beta}} H_{n-1}(X) \xrightarrow{\cdot p}H_{n-1}(X) \to \dots$$

From that, we obtain a s.e.s.

$$0 \to \mathrm{coker}(\_ \cdot p) \to H_n(X; \mathbb{Z}_p) \to \ker(\_ \cdot p) \to 0.$$

Where $\mathrm{coker}(\_ \cdot p) \cong H_n(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\ker(\_ \cdot p) \cong \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p)$. Thus,

$$0 \to H_n(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p \to H_n(X; \mathbb{Z}_p) \to \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p) \to 0.$$

In that spirit, $\mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}_p)$ is obtained from the free resolution induced by $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0$.

This should resemble the universal coefficient theorem.